# Can't create partition table using fdisk

Tags: partition, fdisk

I'm having real trouble formatting a new hard drive, whenever I try to create a partition table using fdisk it does not seem to be written to the disk. For example see below for an extract of my command line. The hard drive itself seems to be working fine as I've tested it in another system.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong ?

```
wave@plex:~$ sudo fdisk /dev/sda

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.31.1).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

Device does not contain a recognized partition table.
Created a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0x02c7abee.

Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/sda: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x73ed82ac

Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered.
Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
Syncing disks.

wave@plex:~$ sudo fdisk /dev/sda

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.31.1).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

Device does not contain a recognized partition table.
Created a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0x73ed82ac.

Command (m for help):
```

Comment: fdisk is not a formatting utility, and you've done nothing with it.

Comment: @IporSircer your comment makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: I've tried your commands but couldn't reproduce your problem -- the first fdisk command will actually write an empty partition table (with signature and disk id), and the second one will recognize it. I've tested both with a virtual 1.8TB empty disc, and with an actual --but smaller-- hardware disc on which I zeroed out the mbr. Please update your question with info about your system, if that problem is real and not some mix-up.

Answer (score -1):

You did not create a partition. If you are **VERY** sure the disk doesn't contain any data, try the `n` command and answer its questions.

Comment: try OP's command on a file generated with eg. `dd if=/dev/null of=/tmp/file seek=3907029168`, `fdisk /tmp/file`, etc. and you'll see that fdisk **does** write an empty partition table to it the first time (together with 55AA signature and disk id), and it does recognize it the second time.

Comment: @mosvy: still s/he did not create a partition, which would be the prerequisite for formatting.